# Bash - How to check if all letters in a string are uppercase

Tags: bash

For example:

```
"abc" -> false
"aBc" -> false
"aBC" -> false
"ABC" -> true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pure `bash`, using a regular expression in `[[`:

```
$ [[ abc =~ ^[[:upper:]]+$ ]] && echo "All upper case"
$ [[ aBc =~ ^[[:upper:]]+$ ]] && echo "All upper case"
$ [[ aBC =~ ^[[:upper:]]+$ ]] && echo "All upper case"
$ [[ ABC =~ ^[[:upper:]]+$ ]] && echo "All upper case"
All upper case
```

Comment: It's ok if the string only contain letters. You can try with A2BC

Answer (score 0):

You can try do it by regex match:

```
etoneja@ois ~ $ REGEX='^[A-Z]+$'
etoneja@ois ~ $ echo "ABC" | grep -P -q "$REGEX"
etoneja@ois ~ $ echo $?
0
etoneja@ois ~ $ echo "ABc" | grep -P -q "$REGEX"
etoneja@ois ~ $ echo $?
1
```

0 for success, 1 for fail

*Edited after @Gordon Davisson comment.*

Comment: You should put double-quotes around the variable reference (that is, `grep -P -q "$REGEX"`). Without them, the shell will treat that regex as a glob pattern and try to it into a list of matching filenames, which can cause really weird problems.